# Is there a way to process SignalR data using Spark Streaming?

Tags: signalr, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a data source provided to me using SignalR, which I’ve never used.
I can’t find any documentation on how to ingest it with Spark Streaming, is there a defined process for that?

If not, are there intermediate steps I should take first? Process the data myself from a signal-r client, and create a Kafka producer that’s then reading from that via Structured Streaming?

Alternatively, could try to use airflow but also not sure about that since it’s streaming data.